# File Recovery when Disk Space is not Reclaimed

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery

I have a two disk system, Disk1 which contains OSX and Disk2 for misc files.

I deleted the .Trash folder on Disk1, which I assumed would only affect files on Disk1, but must have had an effect on Disk2.

There was about 500GB of data 'deleted' (This data was never trashed in the first place).

*The free space on Disk2 has not changed.*

I am running data rescue now, but I figure this might be a special case.

Is there any way to get the data back without forensic utilities?

**Later:**

Forensic utils didn't help.

Why is the available disk space unchanged?  Should I zero it to reclaim?

Comment: Did you do this from the terminal?

Comment: how did you delete the .Trash directory?

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard It might have been via terminal as I remember needing sudo, but then again .Trash wasn't all I deleted. It does seems the likely culprit to me.

Comment: can you please go into the terminal, and push the up arrow until you see the command you typed, then copy and paste it here?

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard I'm a dev myself - terminal is a daily tool.  The push up log is long gone.  It seems like you might have an idea.  Can you post it and I will follow through?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly where the data went. I can't do with without some idea of exactly what was typed. How long ago did this occur?

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard It was two days ago - it seems like the data is still there as the space was not reclaimed.  But why would deleting files on Disk1 have had that effect?

Comment: it shouldn't have, which is why I'm curious as to what was typed. The tiniest typo could do unforetold things to a computer.